# How to validate PowerShell Function Parameters allowing empty strings?

Tags: powershell, parameters

Please try this:

```
function f1
{
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [string]
    $Text
    )
    $text
}

function f2
{
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    #[string]
    $Text
    )
    $text
}

function f3
{
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [string]
    $Text
    )
    $text
}

f1 ''
f2 ''
f3 ''
```

Here f1 throws an error. Now try

```
f2 $null 
f3 $null
```

This time only f2 throws an error. What I want is a function f, so that

```
f '' # is accepted
f $null # returns an error
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, your function 'f2' works as you want. f2 '' is accepted and f2 $null generate an error.

Comment: @JPB I think the problem there is about the data type.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The Mandatory attribute blocks null and empty values and prompts you for a value.
To allow empty values (including null) add the [AllowEmptyString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.allowemptystrings?view=netframework-4.8) parameter attribute:

```
function f1
{
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [AllowEmptyString()]
    [string]$Text
    )
    $text
}
```

Comment: Your version is better than that of Roman Kuzmin, it rejects non strings like f1 @(1, 2).  The fact that f1 $null is accepted seems to be the slightest problem. BTW this nearly identical to f3.

Comment: Try to replace AllowEmptyString with ValidateNotNull. it allows empty strings but not nulls.

Comment: No, ValidateNotNull() fails for f1 ''.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the solution that fits the requirements with a caveat.

```
function f1
{
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    $Text
    )
    Write-Host 'Working'
    $text
}

f1 ''
f1 $null
```

Output:

```
Working
f1 : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Text' because it is null.
```

**Caveat**

In order to fit the requirements we have to omit the explicit type declaration of `[string]`. The problem is that PowerShell tends to convert nulls to empty strings everywhere where the `[string]` type is specified. Thus, if we use the type declaration then null value actually never comes to the function.

P.S. Here is a related issue submitted:
[It isn't possible to pass null as null into a .NET method that has a parameter of type String](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/307821/it-isnt-possible-to-pass-null-as-null-into-a-net-method-that-has-a-parameter-of-type-string)

Comment: I have just realized that this is exactly the `function f2`. So, that is not quite a real answer, perhaps :)

Comment: +1 That what I'am saying from the begining ;o) But you give the explanation, you are the guy.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness, if you want your input be validated against string type, you can do it afterward parameters declaration:

```
function f1
{
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    $Text
    )
    if (!($text -eq '') -and !($text -as [string])) {write-host "wrong type"; return }
    $text
}
```

This function behaves as follows:

- Throws "Cannot bind argument.." exception when input is `$null`
- Passes when input is an empty string
- Exits with message *wrong type* when input is not a string