# How to validate PowerShell Function Parameters allowing empty arrays?

Tags: function, validation, powershell

I have a problem similar to [THIS ONE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403342/how-to-validate-powershell-function-parameters-allowing-empty-strings)

I'm passing to a function 3 arrays and I validate object type this way

```
function _TEST {
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)]
    [array]$Path,
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)]
    [array]$RW,
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)]
    [array]$RO
)
process {
    # my code
}
```

It works unless I pass to function array without elements, in that case it returns this error `_TEST : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty collection.`

Is there a way to solve the problem similar to `[AllowEmptyString()]` in linked question or do I have to write custom code to test input variable?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this:

```
param (
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)]
    [AllowEmptyCollection()]
    [array]$Path
)
```

**Link:**

[Parameter Validation Attributes](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15994.powershell-advanced-function-parameter-attributes.aspx)

Comment: Using this code it allows also objects different from array: 
`_TEST @()` --> no errors ; 
`_TEST "string"` --> no errors